# is there a way to decouple the screen saver activity timer from the lock timer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm looking for a way to separate the functionality of "lock the PC" from "activate a screensaver" or "turn off the display".

In my ideal world, these two functions would be on separate internal timers, and there's some powershell or other CLI/API that I could call to reset these timers independently...

at least as far as I've been able to figure out, the only way to separate these functions is the black-and-white ability to "not lock the PC when the screen saver activates" ... but what I'm looking for is something more along the lines of:

"after XXX seconds of inactivity I want to turn off the display, and (separately) after YYY seconds of inactivity I want to lock the PC".

Also helpful would be some way to "reset the inactivity timer but ONLY the timer that applies to the turn off display or only applies to locking the machine"

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides exactly what you want: There are actually *multiple* timers for Windows screen blanking/saver, for Sleep and for actually *locking* the PC.

- The Windows Power and Sleep settings can be accessed easily from the Control Panel.

[image: Power & sleep settings]

- There is a Registry setting for a **grace period**, i.e., the time duration from the screen blanking (or screen saver starting) and Windows actually being locked. If you move the mouse, hit a key or otherwise resume from the blanked state before the grace period elapses, there is *no* logon needed.

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ScreenSaverGracePeriod
  ```

[image: Screen Saver Grace Period]

Note 1: In the example above from Windows 10, the value *ScreenSaverGracePeriod* for 180 seconds (three minutes) is a REG_DWORD, i.e., numerical. Some sources state use a string, REG_SZ, instead, on some versions of Windows.

Note 2: Screen Saver Grace Period may be [controlled by a Group Policy setting](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/using-group-policy-object-preferences-modify-screen-saver-grace-period), so may be blocked by IT.

Note 3: There may be some interactions between theses timers, as discussed at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/970625/registry-setting-windows-lock-screen-grace-period).